# Problem installing REST Server module

Tags: 6, installation

When I attempt to enable the [REST Server](http://drupal.org/project/rest_server) module, I get the following error message:

> A library is missing for rest_server to work (Currently using Missing library Please download spyc and create a file called spyc.php in rest_server/lib)

The spyc.php file is included with the module in the `rest_server/lib` directory, but the error is still reported, and prevents the module from being enabled.

Drupal version: **6.22**

Rest Server module version: **6.x-2.0-beta3**

[I reported the issue](http://drupal.org/node/1349836) on the module page.

Just wondering if you see any patterns that could help me debug this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on this folder ? [Securing file permissions and ownership](http://drupal.org/node/244924)

Comment: I have checked and they're set correctly. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download spyc from [http://code.google.com/p/spyc/](http://code.google.com/p/spyc/downloads/detail?name=spyc-0.5.zip). Inside the spyc folder find the file called spyc.php and copy it to the Services Module 'servers/rest_server/lib/' directory.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed the error message meant the `modules/rest_server/lib/` directory.

Comment: @drebables Thanks for pointing out the correct location.

Comment: Well, I must be forgotting something. I download spyc.php from the link, I put it on servers/rest_server/lib/ but the installer still disallowing me to activate Rest server option. Permissions are OK and I already have launch update script in modules.

Answer (score 0):

after you put the spyc.php in the modules/services/servers/rest_server/lib folder, go the the Modules configuration, disable the REST server, then re-enable it.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some places you can put rpyc (download from http://code.google.com/p/spyc/downloads/detail?name=spyc-0.5.zip):

```
servers/rest_server/lib
modules/services/servers/rest_server/lib
profiles/<someprofiles>/modules/services/servers/rest_server/lib
```

Hope this help