# Where place spyc library dependencies

Tags: services, 8, theming

I have a issue trying to activate REST SERVER from services. I need to add this library. I'm using drupal 7.19 on Ubuntu.

Reading [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16021/problem-installing-rest-server-module#_=_) question, I add the spyc.php in 'servers/rest_server/lib/'

But where I must place the rest of files?

Reading [the issue](http://drupal.org/node/1349588), #2 suggest that the best solution will be allow to place the library on 'sites/all/libraries', this doesn't work in my version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was I hadn't the dependency `libraries` . Just [downloading this](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) module, updating, and adding the spyc.php in 'servers/rest_server/lib/' Rest server will work.

Answer (score 3):

I placed the spyc.php file in /sites/all/libraries/spyc/ and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You have to place it in `sites/all/libraries/spyc` folder.

For example, download Spyc.php by the following drush (>7.x) one-liner:

```
drush --no-core -y make <(printf "core = 7.x\nlibraries[spyc][directory_name] = spyc\nlibraries[spyc][download][type] = file\nlibraries[spyc][type] = library\nlibraries[spyc][download][url] = https://raw.github.com/mustangostang/spyc/master/Spyc.php")
```

or manually:

```
mkdir sites/all/libraries/spyc
wget -P sites/all/libraries/spyc https://raw.github.com/mustangostang/spyc/master/Spyc.php
```